# ExecuteNonQuery Result in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, executenonquery

How can i know if i create a database successfully? I am using `"CREATE DATABASE DemoDB"` as a SQL command. `ExecuteNonQuery()` method returns 0. What should i use to understand if i created a database successfully?

Comment: You need to read up on what mysql give's you to understand what you can do with a database. Once you know what can be done then you can easily verify it's been created correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery throws a MySqlException exception if there is an error. It returns 0 if successful but you don't need to check the return value; if it returns normally it has succeeded. For example here is the exception I get when I try to create a database that already exists:

**Can't create database *'name'*; database exists**

Answer (score 2):

As MSDN says:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

Comment: Not sure how that helps answer the question?  And even so, the OP says that in this case the return value is 0.

Answer (score 2):

ExecuteNonQuery will return 0 for a CREATE DATABASE command because it returns the **rows** changed by your query.

This will return some rows if the DB exists:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'DemoDB'
```

Comment: Whilst this might suffice insofar as one can discover whether the desired database exists, it doesn't actually answer the question insofar as discovering whether the command succeeded or failed.